# Buscar dia, hora e adicionar classe a um form

Tags: classes, data

fiz uma pergunta a um tempo atrás aqui e me ajudaram muito. Consegui fazer um código buscando o dia da semana (sábado e domingo) e adicionando uma classe ao form para desativar ele. Segue:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    now = new Date
    var idBotaoEnviar = $("#form-reserva");
    now.getDay() == 0  || now.getDay() == 6 || now.getDay(5) && now.getHours() >= 18 ? '' : $(idBotaoEnviar).addClass('ativado')
    console.log(now)
});
```

Precisava adicionar a esse código uma forma que quando for sexta-feira depois das 19h, ele adicione a classe também para desativar o form.

Esse código acima, está adicionando a classe todo dia depois das 19h.

Conseguem me ajudar? Agradeço muito.
Sou bem iniciante pelo que podem ver rs'.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você tem o código feito, só adaptar.

```
now.getDay() == 5 && now.getHours() >= 19 ? '' : $(idBotaoEnviar).addClass('desativado');
```

Comment: Tá joia meu amigo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Vou ajustar lá e posto aqui o resultado.